# How to restore Windows Live Writer settings?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, import, windows-live-writer

I copied the contents of my hard drive (which had WinXP istalled) elsewhere, wiped it clean and installed Windows 7.

One thing I forgot is the UserID/Passwords to all the blogs I've setup in Windows Live Writer.  Is it possible to go through the contents of the old hard drive, retrieve them and import them into the new instance of the Live Writer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Windows Live Writer passwords are encrypted, so unfortunately you won't be able to restore them. I recommend that you go to each of your blog's web page and choose the "Forgot my password" link to reset your password.

-Will
Windows Live Writer Developer